# Trying to debug a Kentico website but cant

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, kentico

I have a Kentico website project and I wish to debug and develop content on Kentico. I am a c# developer and wish to use Visual Studio Code. 
How can I open the website in Visual Studio Code 2019 and work with it?

I have the website open in my Visual Studio Code and can't find the contents of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Kentico is .NET application and you can't run it with Visual Studio Code, you need regular [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/).

Anyway you won't be able to edit content in VS. Content sits in MS SQL database and is edited through Kentico admin section. To get there you'll have to deploy Kentico source code to IIS, database to SQL server, connect them and run in browser.